# Enforce function argument class type in javascript (for type safety and to help browser JIT/compiler optimize)

Tags: javascript, performance, types, typechecking

Most javascript libraries which try to achieve [high performance math](https://github.com/mattdesl/vecmath/blob/master/lib/Vector2.js) (e.g. for graphics or physics simulation) use tricks like this to make sure compiler knows that variables are of numerical type:

```
    function Vector3( x, y, z ) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
        this.z = z || 0;
    }

    function Vector3( x, y, z ) {
        this.x = x + 0.0;
        this.y = y + 0.0;
        this.z = z + 0.0;
    }
```

Does it make sence to push this on next level, and ensure type not only of primitives but also of classes? E.g. something like

```
function Sphere( pos, R ) {
    let junk = 0.0 + pos.x + pos.y + pos.z;
    this.pos = pos;
    this.R   = R + 0.0;
}

function Sphere( pos, R ) {
     if ( pos instanceof Vector3 ){
          this.pos = pos;
     }else{
          this.pos = Vector3(pos);
     }
     this.R   = R + 0.0;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Does it make sense from preformance point of view?
2. Isn't `instanceof` too slow ?
3. Is this possible to do more nicley, with less boilerplate?

**on TypeScript etc.**

I know there are things like [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) but they require to install specific environment, and as far as I know, they are not directly supported by web-browsers, and the type-anotation does not help js-engine in browser to optimize. ( Maybe I'm wrong - I would be glad if you correct me )

Comment: The first snippet demonstrates default parameters, nothing to do with performance. The second snippet doesn't do anything useful, as far as I can tell (and is not found in your link). `x|0` (single bar, not double) coerces to integer, and can be used to comply with [asm.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js) (which does increase performance).

Comment: yes, asm.js ... I think I saw `x|0` exactly in that context some time ago. But my question is - how to do smething like that for non-primitive types like classes.

Comment: asm.js [cannot use classes](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#types), so it's a moot point.

Comment: Typescript helps you to use the correct types while coding, but it doesn't cast variables to specified types in run-time. It only provides coding tools for maintainability, but it's compiled to javascript at the end so you will need to do the same checks and assignments.